# How to add two line graph together in Tableau without changing their values?

Tags: graph, tableau-api

I'm trying to combine two line graphs in Tableau as one. However, when I do that, the percentage of the total number of records changed (from the percentage of one year to the percentage of both years).Not sure how I can fix this.

[percentage of total number of record for 2016/2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2a5t.png)
[percentage of total number of 2016 plus 2017 (wrong)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDiFK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the table calculation. Go to Advanced. It should Computer Using [Year] and [Month]. Make sure [Year] is the top of the list of compute using fields you specify. Then Restart the calculation every [Year]